# Memory hack to transpose matrix corrupts stack, C++

Tags: c++, pointers, stack, pointer-arithmetic, stack-corruption

I need to implement a matrix transpose procedure in C++.
The problem is the signature, the function has to be called like this:

```
transpose(in_mat[0][0], n, m, out_mat[0][0])
```

where n and m are the dimensions.
All values are doubles, both the matrices and the dimensions.

Since the code is automatically generated, I can't fix this.

My workaround looks like this:

```
void transpose(double& in_mat, const double _n, const double _m, double& out_mat)
{
    int n = _n, m = _m;
    double* in_pointer= &in_mat;
    double* out_pointer= &out_mat;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            *(out_pointer+(j*n+i)) = *(in_pointer+(i*m + j));
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine.
I've constructed a test case with two matrices of different width and height. One is filled with random numbers, the other is filled with zeros. Then the transpose procedure is called and the two matrices are compared.
The functionality is correct.

But it corrupts the stack. When run in Visual Studio 2015 there is a warning

> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'in_mat' was corrupted.

What did I do wrong ? Why is the stack corrupted ?
Code after the invocation of transpose works correctly.

EDIT:

Here is the complete setup:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

void transpose(double& in_mat, const double _n, const double _m, double& out_mat)
{
    int n = _n, m = _m;
    double* in_pointer = &in_mat;
    double* out_pointer = &out_mat;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            *(out_pointer+(j*n+i)) = *(in_pointer+(i*m + j));
        }
    }
}


int main()
{

    double in_mat[5][4];
    double out_mat[4][5];// assign matrix

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            in_mat[i][j] = std::rand();
            out_mat[j][i] = 0;
        }
    }

    double n = 5;
    double m = 4;

    transpose(in_mat[0][0], n, m, out_mat[0][0]);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            if (in_mat[i][j] - out_mat[j][i]>0.0001) {
                std::cout << "code is broken" << std::endl; //never reached
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << "finished" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: C doesn't have references. If you program in C++, please specify C++, not C.

Comment: You're right. I fixed it.

Comment: How big are those matrices? Have you considered allocating them on the heap instead?

Comment: @simpel01 - why would that matter? it's an array - contiguous block of memory that holds m*n entries

Comment: It matters because depending on the system you are running on, the stack size for a function is limited. Therefore when `transpose` is invoked, its activation record is going to corrupt either one or both the matrices which are allocated in the caller activation record.

Comment: Please recognize that `*(a+b)` is equal to `a[b]` unless operator overloading is going on. Why do you use the former syntax?

Comment: if you go for heap, then you'd get heap corruption. The root cause seems to be buffer overrun.

Comment: out_pointer+(j*n+i) does not seem correct. have you traced this for a 3x4 test matrix on paper?

Comment: what are the types of in_mat and out_mat? show the code allocating them.

Comment: I know this is going to sound strange and all, but can you show us how `in_mat` and `out_mat` are constructed? are you positive that this matrix isn't built with `float`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your subscripts (or loop limits) were backwards where you initialized the matrices.

You have

```
double in_mat[5][4];
double out_mat[4][5];// assign matrix

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        in_mat[i][j] = std::rand();
        out_mat[j][i] = 0;
    }
}
```

When `j==4` you are writing beyond the end of `out_mat`